# Establish internet connection with LTE card and netplan

Tags: netplan

I want to change the internet connection from ethernet cable to an LTE sim card. For this, I need to configure the netplan .yaml file correctly.

The current file is

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   es160:
     dhcp4: yes
     dhcp6: no
```

How would I need to configure this file so that an LTE connection is established?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A cellular connection is a modem connection, so the device type have to be `modems` instead of `ethernets`.
2. The [netplan documentation](https://netplan.io/reference/#properties-for-device-type-modems%3A) says:

> GSM/CDMA modem configuration is only supported for the NetworkManager
> backend. systemd-networkd does not support modems.

Therefore you have to use `NetworkManager` instead of `Networkd` as renderer.
To use it you have to install NetworkManager and ModemManager first. Install it as described in the [networkManager documentation](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/installation) :

```
snap install network-manager
```

and

```
snap install modem-manager
```

3. For an easy setup you can use:

```
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  modems:
    <INTERFACE_NAME>:
      auto-config: true
      pin: <PIN>
```

Answer (score 3):

Long time listener, first time caller...

I didn't even learn this my engineer just taught me so I figure I would share:

1. sudo apt install network-manager
2. Update netplan yaml with modem stanza's for device name, apn, and DHCP. The example below uses any cdc-wdm device.

Hopefully this helps someone.

I just overwrote the default yaml in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: true
  modems:
    cdc-wdm:
      apn: yourapnhere
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        name: cdc-wdm*
```